# Examples of measurable spaces and measurable functions other than $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{L}) \to (\mathbb{R}_{+}, \mathcal{B})$.

Tags: measure-theory

I'm studying Lebesgue integration theory. In this theory, we study morphisms from $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{L})$ to $(\mathbb{R}_{+}, \mathcal{B})$.

Are there other interesting or important examples of morphism in the category of measurable spaces and measurable functions?

Comment: Sure, a lot come from probability, for example, stochastic processes $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ with various $\sigma$-algebras.

Comment: There is also a generalization of the integral for banach space valued functions. That is the Bochner integral.